# How to list files containing the range of numbers with GLOBBING?

Tags: linux, list, unix, glob

So for example with the range of numbers 10-20 its easy. I would use:

```
ls *[12][0-9]*
```

But what if the range was for example 00-32 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
ls *{00..32}
```

But be aware, that this will result in 33 separate executions of `ls`, not 1 single execution. When you have for example only one file ending with 31, this file will be listed, but you will get 32 times the error `ls: cannot access your_file00: No such file or directory`.